# SQL ERROR [08001]

Tags: sql, sql-server, error-handling, sql-server-2012

I am getting an error on SQL Server 2012. Whenever I am trying to connect with with the database, I get this error:

> Cannot connect to the database.
>
> ERROR [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB] SQL Serverdoes not exist or access denied.
>
> ERROR [01000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server
>   Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionOpen (Connect()).

[image]

The server is localhost and authorization have also done with the correct username and password but still it is the same result, I have also tried the Windows Authorization

Does anyone know any solution for this error?

Comment: try to connect to a server that does exists or one that you have access to?

Comment: `does not exist or access denied` seems obvious enough... find the server, and/or figure out the credentials you need.

Comment: @MarcB the server is localhost and Authorization have also done with the correct username and password but still it is the same result, i have also tried the windows Authorization

Comment: Is your service for SQL server running?

Comment: @Pinwar13 yes it is running !

Comment: Are you connecting it fr first time after installation? Was it working before? You are getting the error from ssms?

Comment: @Pinwar13 i can login to sql server management by username and password but using the same credential i am getting this error

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Named Pipes and TCP IP protocols are enabled.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to connect from some tool or application from other machine, try by entering the actual server name (SERVERNAME\INSTANCE) instead of localhost.